# Nginx configure subdomain on https, privacy error

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, subdomain, lets-encrypt

I have a domain `ambroise-rabier.fr` and like to add a domain `analytics.ambroise-rabier.fr`, also in https.

On chrome I get **privacy error**, unless I duplicate `ambroise-rabier.fr` value in each server_name key. But then **nginx complain** with `conflicting server name "ambroise-rabier.fr"`.

Here is the config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name ambroise-rabier.fr www.ambroise-rabier.fr analytics.ambroise-rabier.fr;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
          allow all;
          root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name ambroise-rabier.fr www.ambroise-rabier.fr;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ambroise-rabier.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ambroise-rabier.fr/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;


    location / {
        # ...
    }

    root /var/www/html/blog-front/dist/blog-front;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}

# See also https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose
# Se also https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/matomo.conf
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name ambroise-rabier.fr analytics.ambroise-rabier.fr;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ambroise-rabier.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ambroise-rabier.fr/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    root /var/www/html/matomo;

    index index.php;

    # make sure outgoing links don't show the URL to the Matomo instance
    add_header Referrer-Policy origin; 

    location / {
        # ...
    }

}
# vim: filetype=nginx
```

Again, if I remove `ambroise-rabier.fr` from `server_name ambroise-rabier.fr analytics.ambroise-rabier.fr;`, the nginx configuration doesn't throw any warning. But I get **privacy error** on Chrome (that is worse). With my current workaround I suspect some resources might not be loading well on `analytics.ambroise-rabier.fr` due to the duplicate server_name. And there also should be a correct way to achieve this.

I am using docker and Let's Encrypt certificate (followed digital ocean tutorial), I use this command: `certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email my.email@host.fr --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d ambroise-rabier.fr  -d www.ambroise-rabier.fr -d analytics.ambroise-rabier.fr`
.

The output of this command:

```
ambroise@vps318592:~/node_project$ docker-compose up certbot
db is up-to-date
nodejs is up-to-date
webserver is up-to-date
Recreating certbot ... done
Attaching to certbot
certbot      | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
certbot      | Renewing an existing certificate
certbot      | IMPORTANT NOTES:
certbot      |  - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
certbot      |    /etc/letsencrypt/live/ambroise-rabier.fr/fullchain.pem
certbot      |    Your key file has been saved at:
certbot      |    /etc/letsencrypt/live/ambroise-rabier.fr/privkey.pem
certbot      |    Your cert will expire on 2019-09-19. To obtain a new or tweaked
certbot      |    version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot
certbot      |    again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
certbot      |    "certbot renew"
certbot      |  - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:
certbot      |
certbot      |    Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
certbot      |    Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
certbot      |
certbot exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like SSL certificate issue. Can you check the SAN in your certificate whether `analytics.ambroise-rabier.fr` is there? try adding option `--expand` when you generate the certificate.

> --expand tells Certbot to update an existing certificate with a new certificate that contains all of the old domains and one or more additional new domains. With the --expand option, use the -d option to specify all existing domains and one or more new domains.

source: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#re-creating-and-updating-existing-certificates